# .net maui Navigation.PushAsync doesn't seem to do much

Tags: maui, .net-8.0

I have a .net 8 maui project.  I have a tabbed page and navigation page setup for each of my tabs.  Inside of my imagelist page, I have two toolbar items as shown below.  the toolbar items open the camera or the photo library on the device.  When I run the code to open the next page, I don't see the next page beyond the title of the page changing.  This is behavior I am seeing in the android emulator on Win11.  How do I get the next screen to show up?  I've tried several things but no luck.  I've googled with no luck.  any ideas are appreciated.  I've made the picedit page just a label with text and no luck there either.

TIA

Tabbed Page:

```cs
    public class TabbedNavPage : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TabbedPage
    {
        public TabbedNavPage() {
            On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
            var ratePage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()) {
                Title = "Rate",
                IconImageSource = "rate.png"
            };
            var login = new NavigationPage(new Login()) {
                Title = "Login & Account",
                IconImageSource = "account.png"
            };
            var imageList = new NavigationPage(new ImageList()) {
                Title = "Image List",
                IconImageSource = "list.png"
            };
            var img = new NavigationPage(new PicEdit());

            Children.Add(ratePage);
            Children.Add(login);
            Children.Add(imageList);
            Children.Add(img);
}
}
```

Toolbar items:

```xml
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add from camera"
                x:Name="CameraAdd"
                IconImageSource="camera.png"
                Clicked="CameraAdd_Clicked"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add from photo library"
                x:Name="PhotoLibraryAdd"
                IconImageSource="imagelist.png" 
                Clicked="PhotoLibraryAdd_Clicked"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

code to open the camera:

```cs
private async void CameraAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    await GetImageEditorCameraSourceAsync();
}
private async Task GetImageEditorCameraSourceAsync() {
    var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted) {
        // If the camera permission is not granted, request it.
        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted) {
            // If the camera permission is denied by the user,
            // You may show an alert or take appropriate action
            return;
        }
    }

    var photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();

    if (photo != null) {
        var img = ImageSource.FromStream(() => photo.OpenReadAsync().Result);
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new PicEdit() { ImageSource = img });
    }
}
```

The PicEdit page has gone thru various iterations of making this work.  Here is what my most recent version is:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="Hi" />
</VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

***** Added on November 30 9:30 am US Eastern *******

Here is my event handler for just a basic button click in the emulator and to open another page.  It works.

```
private async void Camera_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   await Navigation.PushAsync(new PicEdit());
}
```

When I use the following code to handle the taking of a picture and use it in the emulator, it does not work.  My assumption is that there is something about opening the camera/photo library that leaves something in some state so that a stack or global variable in the .net maui code is messed up.

```
private async void Camera_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported) {
        FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();

        if (photo != null) {
            // save the file into local storage
            string localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);

            using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
            using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

            await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new PicEdit());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code for the PicEdit page? Do you want the photo to be displayed on the PicEdit page after taking the photo?

Comment: I've added the most recent version.  It is just a label as previously mentioned.  I have also tried to load the picture into a syncfusion imageeditor, but that was giving me similar behavior.  I'm just trying to make this as simple as possible.

Comment: I have also updated the findings in my question.  I was tired last night, so I didn't put 100% of what I was seeing in the emulator.  The content is actually displaying but to the right of the collectionview.  I would expect the new content page to be displayed over the top of the current page.  yes, it is within a navigation page.

Comment: I am finding it is some type of problem with opening the camera or photolibrary from the mediapicker.

Comment: I created a constructor containing ‘ImageSourcce’ in the behindcode of PicEditPage, so that passing 'img' as 'ImageSource' to PicEditPage in CameraAdd_Clicked method can achieve your demand

Comment: Thanks @SeanHe-MSFT, but I don’t think that is what I am looking for.  I’ve experimented with a lot of things.  What I am seeing right now is that if I open the photo picker, or camera app, and then get an image, when I push the next view, I don’t get anything beyond the title. I would expect the content of the view.  I’m experimenting more and will post updated data if I have time.

Comment: @Wallanc B. McClure I did a test based on your code. After I took the photo, the view could navigate to the PicEditPage with a label tag. So, I'll wait for your more specific  
 details, and then I can try to re-answer your question.

Comment: I have tried on the device, and am getting similar results.

Comment: Here is what I am currently finding.  It seems that the image editor control only works properly within a grid.  To me, that makes no sense, but it is what I am finding.

Comment: @Wallance B. McClure I previously tested your project on an iPhone device, and the content of PicEdit can normally display after taking a photo. However, when I tested the project on Android today, the issue you mentioned occurred. Therefore, I suggest you create a new issue on GitHub (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues)

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT I’ve been running on android.  I’ve found some other things that the grid tag magically fixes.